# XCODE: The request was denied... (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified

Tags: xcode, environment, workspace

I updated xcode to 10.1 this morning and since then none of my code runs. I am getting the message above (question) which I have researched exhaustively. I have read all the other posts concerning this issue and nothing I have tried seems to work in my situation.  The one difference in my message is the reference to "unspecified".  I have done the following:

- New Provisioning Profile
- Automatically managing sign-in
- Deleting certain keychain certificates
- Project Settings to Legacy
- Rebooting/Cleaning
- Rebooting Simulator
- Mach-O Types to Bundle
- Managing/Editing Schemes
- Creating new user account on Mac.
- New teams/No teams
- etc.

(you get the picture!)

I am at my wits end.  I have been working on this code for a while and short of wiping my machine and re-installing is there anything else that I can do! I am about to explode!!!

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted the machine and I went back to the Build Settings and changed to Mach-O Type back to Executable and it working ow.  Based on all of the previous solutions I have read/tried, this seems about right (unpredictable).